# How to skip namespaces from JSON that was converted from XML?

Tags: android, xml, json, api

This question was first titled: `How to remove -xmlnl tags when I receive JSON from a XML-HTTP-API server?` but now I understand the concept of the problem.

This question is about a exception in `Android` regarding `JSON` translation. I do a `HTTP` `GET` request to a (not-mine) [webserver](http://goo.gl/hFcaJf) made with `c#` and some `api` that, when I call it from a browser, the answer comes in `XML` and when I call it from my `Android` application the result is in `JSON`.

The thing is I am getting an JSON error like: `Value {"-xmlnl:d4p1":"http://schemas..."} of Alternativas of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

The code in XML has this king of content:

```
     <Alternativas xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PainelMonitor.Model"/>
     <Descricao>A primeira fraze que você ouviu hoje foi?</Descricao>
```

I am only interested in the `<Descricao>` content.

This `{"-xmlnl:d4p1":"http://schemas..."}` should not come to JSON and it maked my app crash.

So how could I take it off from my JSON? There are 'tens' of these invalid markups in the code, so I can't do it manually because it is a `Array` of JSON.

Comment: I tried apache camel but couldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your xsl you have to use **

> exclude-result-prefixes=""

** attribute.

Comment: Please, would you show me an example on how and where should I do that?

Comment: Where do you define that namespace?

Comment: I am developing the Android application, not the server API.